# protect PDF document

Tags: pdf

I am adding metadata to my document:

```
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={ddd},
    pdfsubject={aaa},
    pdfauthor={xxx},
    **pdfkeywords={666},**
    pdfproducer={yyy!},
```

And there is a password string here, however the document does not ask for a password when opening it. How to password protect a document?

Comment: `pdfkeywords` is for **key**words, not **pass**words.

Comment: Thank! However, as I understand it, without third-party software, it is not possible to set the password directly from the latex